# Check if date is overlapping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table tblBranchTimingEntry

```
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| BranchEntryID |        fromDate         |         toDate          |     SundayIn     |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|            24 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.0000000 |
|            24 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.0000000 |
|            24 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-03-31 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:00.0000000 |
|            24 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:00.0000000 |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

---

**Requirement**

I am giving input BranchEntryID, fromDate, toDate and I want to check if any date between fromDate and toDate over lap with the date ranges stored in tblBranchTimingEntry.

---

**What I done so far**

I have this query

```
SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        [dbo].[tblBranchTimingEntry] 

    WHERE
        BranchEntryId = 24
    AND
        ('2015-01-14' BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate OR '2015-02-28' BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate)
```

This will check the overlap.

---

**Problem**

This will work only if the input date falls between the dates present in DB.
This will fail in this example.

Suppose I'm giving fromdate and todate as '2015-02-16' and '2015-08-27',
this query will not return anything. But there are dates overlapping between these date.

ANy Solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
SELECT te.* 
FROM [dbo].[tblBranchTimingEntry]  te
WHERE BranchEntryId = 24 AND
      '2015-01-14' < toDate AND
      '2015-02-28' > fromDate;
```

Depending on what you mean by "overlapping" that could be `<=` and/or `>=`.

The logic is:  two date ranges overlap is the first starts before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM
        [dbo].[tblBranchTimingEntry]
WHERE
    BranchEntryId = 24
AND
    (('2015-01-14' < toDate AND
  '2015-01-14' > fromDate) or ('2015-02-28' > fromDate and '2015-02-28' < toDate) or ('2015-02-28' > toDate AND
  '2015-01-14' < fromDate))
```

That way you are checking if any of the dates is betwwen the fromDate and ToDate