# sql select date in range

Tags: mysql, date

Table:

```
id | u_id | start_date |  end_date  |
-------------------------------------
01 |   7  | 2015-05-05 | 2015-07-23 |
02 |   4  | 2015-07-10 | 2015-07-15 |
03 |   4  | 2015-08-27 | 2015-11-05 |
04 |   5  | 2015-08-01 | 2015-12-09 |
```

Need these rows:

```
03 |   4  | 2015-08-27 | 2012-11-05 |
04 |   5  | 2015-08-01 | 2012-12-09 |
```

input data that I have for query: 
`start_date = 2015-10-01` and `end_date = 2015-10-31`

Comment: pick : mysql or sql server

Comment: this is mysql server

Comment: There seems to be an error in `end_date` values of the expected result set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: This is called "overlapping". There are tons of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673310/check-if-date-is-overlapping-in-sql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date 
FROM mytable
WHERE start_date <= @end_date AND end_date >= @start_date
```

The above will return all records whose `start_date - end_date` interval *overlaps* with `@start_date - @end_date`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98107/1)